# For Each Next code, how can I make the code to start from the newest to oldest?

Tags: excel, foreach, outlook, vba

Please refer to the code below. The code will be in Excel VBA and then run it in order to extract a large amount of email in Outlook. I have the second question and need your help. Let's say my "Inbox" has around 400+ emails. Now. the following "For each next " code starts to look in the oldest email! So how can I change the code if the code starts from the newest?

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub GetFromInbox()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Namespace
    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim i, ij As Integer
    Dim tt As Date

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 1
    ij = 0
    x = Date

    ' Now. the following "For each next " code starts to look in the oldest email!
    ' So how can I change the code if the code starts from the newest?
    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
        ij = ij + 1
        'If IsNumeric((Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))) Then
            Sheets("test").Range("a1").Select
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").Clear
            Sheets("test").Range("I2") = ij
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").Value = (Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
            Sheets("test").Range("I1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
            tt = Sheets("test").Range("I1")
            ' MsgBox ("Y-tt=" & tt & " receivedtime=" & olMail.ReceivedTime)
        'Else
            'tt = 0
            'MsgBox ("N-tt=" & tt & " receivedtime=" & olMail.ReceivedTime)
        'End If
        ' tt = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
        If tt >= Range("H1") Then
            'If InStr(olMail.Subject, "others") > 0 And tt >= Range("h1") Then
            If InStr(olMail.Subject, "others") > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("h2") = "y"
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Subject
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.SenderName
                tt = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = CDate(Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yy"))
                ' tt = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = (Format(olMail.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm"))
                MsgBox ("tt=" & tt)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Else
            Sheets("test").Range("h2") = "N"
        End If
    Next olMail

    Set Fldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    'tt = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: How about trying `For i = Fldr.Items.Count to 1 Step -1` ?

Comment: what about olmail ? olmail is the main function in For Each Next code!!! The above code --I serach it via internet and then change/update for my case!!! From my understanding, olmail is referring to each mail in "inbox" !! so your idea may not work but I am not sure !!! Please tell me if I am wrong

Comment: In this scenario you would replace `olMail` with `Fldr.Items(i)`. And since you are already using `i`, you could replace it with another variable name (like "`j`").

Comment: ^^ and, to make the minimal amount of changes to your code, just use `Set olMail = Fldr.Items(j)` immediately after the `For j = Fldr.Items.Count To 1 Step -1` line.  That will limit the number of changes to be just 4 lines - (1) the declaration of j (2) the `For` line (3) the new `Set olMail` line (4) the `Next` line.

Comment: Thanks all the above !! It works !! It is wonderful !!

Answer (score 0):

Sort the items to be sure of the order.

```
Sub ItemsInReliableOrder()

    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-sort-method-outlook

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Namespace

    ' 2007 and subsequent
    Dim Fldr As Folder

    ' Allows for any type of item in folder
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set myItems = Fldr.Items

    myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    For Each myItem In myItems

        If myItem.class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.ReceivedTime
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not a mailitem."
        End If

    Next myItem

    Set Fldr = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set myItem = Nothing
    Set myItems = Nothing

End Sub
```

Do not sort Fldr.Items directly, set a collection of items then sort. Avoid using olMail as a variable name it already has a meaning.

Comment: Hi everyone Today I tried to put the above codes in Outlook& Excel 2016 but all the codes are not working . In the past I used Outlook & Excel 2013. do anyone know why?

Comment: @Bnf there is only me here. If you have already updated the Trust Centre to allow macros then post a new question. Indicate you have enabled macros and whether you have other code that runs, describe what you tried and be more descriptive than "not working".

Comment: Hi everyone : at the beginning, I tried to run the above code and then got "user-define" warning & stopped to run it.  Today, I had found the problem to solve it out. --I had to click on < tools> , then click on < reference> and choose <outlook ..>. After that I could run it.

Comment: Now I have the other question ---If my outlook has around 4 email address and i want to extract a specific folder (not default folder --inbox/sent/ etc)  . How can I specific the exactly email address and the specific folder?

Comment: @Bnf nobody but me would be notified about your comments on **my** answer. You may ask a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask about specifying email addresses and folders. There will be much more room for details.